# Accessing child props from the parent

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm building a d3 interface using react. I want the api to be as simple as possible, and to that end I've concieved the following line chart component.

```
<Chart type="line" multiseries="true">
    <Line data={[...]} label="line1" />
    <Line data={[....]} label="line2" interpolate="linear" />
</Chart>
```

The problem I'm having is that each line needs a common scale, and to generate that I need to find the data set with the maximum range of values to use as the scale.

I have accomplished this in two ways. The first way is by having a `LineChart` component and passing all the data in as a big object like this

```
const config = { line1 : { data: [...] }, line2: { data: [...], interpolate: 'linear' } };
<LineChart config={config} />
```

This has the benfit of making the lines easy to generate, `LineChart` creates the `Line` components with the propper scale for us since it has immediate access to all the data. The downside is that this feels cumbersome compared to the first option, and it requires looping through the object to get all the data properties out.

The second way is using the api as depicted above and looping through `this.props.children` to get the data attributes of each child.

```
const children = this.props.children.isArray() ? this.props.children : [this.props.children]
const data = children.map( child => (child.data) )
```

This feels like an anti-pattern since react is all about composition and uni-directional data flow. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really nothing wrong with accessing props set by child components, and in fact, React provides the `Children` top-level API just for that use case:

```
var data = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => child.props.data);
```

The `React.Children.*` apis normalize children so that you don't have to worry about whether or not a single child was passed or multiple.

From [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children):

> **React.Children**
>   React.Children provides utilities for dealing with the this.props.children opaque data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your option 2 is the correct one. If Chart needs to calculate something based on a piece of data then that piece of data is a prop of Chart, not a prop of Line.

You can make the whole Chart more flexible by making config an array instead of object. It's easier to loop through and you could have any number of lines.

```
const config = [ 
    { data: [...] },
    { data: [...], interpolate: 'linear' },
];

<LineChart config={config} />
```